# Entity Framework not considering the 2nd level of relational data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a class like this

```
public partial class TblCrrequests
{
        public TblCrrequests()
        {
            TblCrExternalBudget = new HashSet<TblCrExternalBudget>();
        }

        public int CrId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
       
        public virtual ICollection<TblCrExternalBudget> TblCrExternalBudget { get; set; }
}

public partial class TblCrExternalBudget
{
        public int? CrId { get; set; }
        public int? TypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual TblCrrequests Cr { get; set; }
        public virtual TblExternalBudgetTypes Type { get; set; }
}

public partial class TblExternalBudgetTypes
{
        public TblExternalBudgetTypes()
        {
            TblCrExternalBudget = new HashSet<TblCrExternalBudget>();
        }

        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TblCrExternalBudget> TblCrExternalBudget { get; set; }
}
```

So to fetch all data of type `TblCrrequests`, I wrote this code

```
List<TblCrrequests> mycr = _context.TblCrrequests
                    .Include(m => m.TblCrExternalBudget)
                    .Where(x => x.ProjectCode == pcode)
                    .OrderByDescending(d => d.RequestedOn)
                    .Take(8)
                    .ToList<TblCrrequests>();
```

But it doesn't return the 3rd level `TblExternalBudgetTypes`.

So I tried `ThenInlcude` like this which triggered an error:

```
List<TblCrrequests> mycr = _context.TblCrrequests
                    .Include(m => m.TblCrExternalBudget).ThenInclude(n => n.TblExternalBudgetTypes)
                    .Include(m => m.TblCrInternalbudget)
                    .Where(x => x.ProjectCode == pcode)
                    .OrderByDescending(d => d.RequestedOn)
                    .Take(8)
                    .ToList<TblCrrequests>();
```

Error:

> 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'TblExternalBudgetTypes' and no accessible extension method 'TblExternalBudgetTypes' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection' could be found

What I did wrong or how should I get the 3rd table data in that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TblCrExternalBudget` has property `Type` of `TblExternalBudgetTypes` type, so you need to do:

```
List<TblCrrequests> mycr = _context.TblCrrequests
                .Include(m => m.TblCrExternalBudget)
                     .ThenInclude(n => n.Type)
                ...
```